# Text delimiters

Tags: symbols, delimiters

Are there characters in latex for separating text? To place where one thought ends and another begins[image]

Comment: You may be interested in `pgfornaments`: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/pgfornament/doc/ornaments.pdf

Comment: Yes you are right! This is what I was looking for. It remains to install correctly

Comment: I don't know where to put the archive. AAAA

Comment: I suggest you to install it from your package manager: in MiKTeX, go to Packages and install it from there; with Tex Live, go to the command prompt or terminal and search `tlmgr install pgfornaments` (`sudo tlmgr ...` in Linux, `cmd` with administrator privileges in Windows).